# Java: create shadow effect on image

Tags: java, image, swing

I'm trying to create a shadow effect (with java) on an image.

I've seen multiple related questions and I've implemented several of the suggested solutions. Unfortunately I always have the same problem: the shadow effect repaints the entire image in gray (i.e. the shadow color) - hence the original image is not visible anymore.

Example of code I tested (based on the JIDE freely available library):

```
ShadowFactory sf = new ShadowFactory(2, 0.5f, Color.black);
ImageIO.write(sf.createShadow(ImageIO.read(new File("c:\\out2.png"))), "png", new File("c:\\out3.png"));
```

No need to says that I tested this with multiple source files (out2.png).

I'm clueless: any hint/help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The over all theory is simple.  Basically, you need to generate a mask of the image (using a `AlphaComposite` and fill that resulting image with the color you want (also using an `AlphaComposite`.  This, of course, all works on the alpha channel of the image...

Once you have that mask, you need to combine the two images (overlaying the original image with the masked image)

This examples make use of [JHLabs filters](http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/index.html) to supply the blur...

[image]

```
public class TestImageDropShadow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestImageDropShadow();
    }

    public TestImageDropShadow() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new ImagePane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class ImagePane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage background;

        public ImagePane() {
            try {
                BufferedImage master = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/Scaled.png"));
                background = applyShadow(master, 5, Color.BLACK, 0.5f);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(TestImageDropShadow.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return background == null ? super.getPreferredSize() : new Dimension(background.getWidth(), background.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (background != null) {
                int x = (getWidth() - background.getWidth()) / 2;
                int y = (getHeight() - background.getHeight()) / 2;
                g.drawImage(background, x, y, this);
            }
        }

    }

    public static void applyQualityRenderingHints(Graphics2D g2d) {
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);
    }

    public static BufferedImage createCompatibleImage(int width, int height) {
        return createCompatibleImage(width, height, Transparency.TRANSLUCENT);
    }

    public static BufferedImage createCompatibleImage(int width, int height, int transparency) {
        BufferedImage image = getGraphicsConfiguration().createCompatibleImage(width, height, transparency);
        image.coerceData(true);
        return image;
    }

    public static BufferedImage createCompatibleImage(BufferedImage image) {
        return createCompatibleImage(image, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
    }

    public static BufferedImage createCompatibleImage(BufferedImage image,
            int width, int height) {
        return getGraphicsConfiguration().createCompatibleImage(width, height, image.getTransparency());
    }

    public static GraphicsConfiguration getGraphicsConfiguration() {
        return GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration();
    }

    public static BufferedImage generateMask(BufferedImage imgSource, Color color, float alpha) {
        int imgWidth = imgSource.getWidth();
        int imgHeight = imgSource.getHeight();

        BufferedImage imgBlur = createCompatibleImage(imgWidth, imgHeight);
        Graphics2D g2 = imgBlur.createGraphics();
        applyQualityRenderingHints(g2);

        g2.drawImage(imgSource, 0, 0, null);
        g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_IN, alpha));
        g2.setColor(color);

        g2.fillRect(0, 0, imgSource.getWidth(), imgSource.getHeight());
        g2.dispose();

        return imgBlur;
    }

    public static BufferedImage generateBlur(BufferedImage imgSource, int size, Color color, float alpha) {
        GaussianFilter filter = new GaussianFilter(size);

        int imgWidth = imgSource.getWidth();
        int imgHeight = imgSource.getHeight();

        BufferedImage imgBlur = createCompatibleImage(imgWidth, imgHeight);
        Graphics2D g2 = imgBlur.createGraphics();
        applyQualityRenderingHints(g2);

        g2.drawImage(imgSource, 0, 0, null);
        g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_IN, alpha));
        g2.setColor(color);

        g2.fillRect(0, 0, imgSource.getWidth(), imgSource.getHeight());
        g2.dispose();

        imgBlur = filter.filter(imgBlur, null);

        return imgBlur;
    }

    public static BufferedImage applyShadow(BufferedImage imgSource, int size, Color color, float alpha) {
        BufferedImage result = createCompatibleImage(imgSource, imgSource.getWidth() + (size * 2), imgSource.getHeight() + (size * 2));
        Graphics2D g2d = result.createGraphics();
        g2d.drawImage(generateShadow(imgSource, size, color, alpha), size, size, null);
        g2d.drawImage(imgSource, 0, 0, null);
        g2d.dispose();

        return result;
    }

    public static BufferedImage generateShadow(BufferedImage imgSource, int size, Color color, float alpha) {
        int imgWidth = imgSource.getWidth() + (size * 2);
        int imgHeight = imgSource.getHeight() + (size * 2);

        BufferedImage imgMask = createCompatibleImage(imgWidth, imgHeight);
        Graphics2D g2 = imgMask.createGraphics();
        applyQualityRenderingHints(g2);

        int x = Math.round((imgWidth - imgSource.getWidth()) / 2f);
        int y = Math.round((imgHeight - imgSource.getHeight()) / 2f);
        g2.drawImage(imgSource, x, y, null);
        g2.dispose();

        // ---- Blur here ---

        BufferedImage imgGlow = generateBlur(imgMask, (size * 2), color, alpha);

        return imgGlow;
    }

    public static Image applyMask(BufferedImage sourceImage, BufferedImage maskImage) {
        return applyMask(sourceImage, maskImage, AlphaComposite.DST_IN);
    }

    public static BufferedImage applyMask(BufferedImage sourceImage, BufferedImage maskImage, int method) {
        BufferedImage maskedImage = null;
        if (sourceImage != null) {

            int width = maskImage.getWidth(null);
            int height = maskImage.getHeight(null);

            maskedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            Graphics2D mg = maskedImage.createGraphics();

            int x = (width - sourceImage.getWidth(null)) / 2;
            int y = (height - sourceImage.getHeight(null)) / 2;

            mg.drawImage(sourceImage, x, y, null);
            mg.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(method));

            mg.drawImage(maskImage, 0, 0, null);

            mg.dispose();
        }
        return maskedImage;
    }
}
```

Comment: @GuillaumePolet Stolen and adapted from Chet of "Filthy Rich Clients"

Comment: Yet, remains pretty cool. Btw, I have seen lots of people mentionning "Filthy rich clients". I feel dumb, but what is this?

Comment: Filthy Rich Clients is a book that explores advance UI design in Java. It's an interesting read for gathering techniques and ideas. Google it & if you're after a book with advanced/different ideas, grab a copy

Comment: Thanks - your sample hinted me to the solution: I needed to use the generated image as background and simply draw the original image on top of it...

Comment: @DavidKroukamp it's similar in concept to what you just presented, just with the addition of a blur ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is my Version:

```
private static Image dropShadow(BufferedImage img) {
    // a filter which converts all colors except 0 to black
    ImageProducer prod = new FilteredImageSource(img.getSource(), new RGBImageFilter() {
        @Override
        public int filterRGB(int x, int y, int rgb) {
            if (rgb == 0)
                return 0;
            else
                return 0xff000000;
        }
    });
    // create whe black image
    Image shadow = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(prod);

    // result
    BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), img.getType());
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) result.getGraphics();

    // draw shadow with offset
    g.drawImage(shadow, 10, 0, null);
    // draw original image
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Good Solution. Works for me in a similar way (had other specs for shadow) and this is very performant