# image with shadow and rounded edges in java swing

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

I'm trying to add an image to [this RoundedPane](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13369038/1989579) with rounded corners and shadow. But I fail to get it.

I made ​​the panel extends from this class

```
public class JPanelConFondo extends JPanel {

    private Image imagen;

    public JPanelConFondo() {
    }

    public JPanelConFondo(String nombreImagen) {
        if (nombreImagen != null) {
            imagen = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(nombreImagen)).getImage();
        }
    }

    public JPanelConFondo(Image imagenInicial) {
        if (imagenInicial != null) {
            imagen = imagenInicial;
        }
    }

    public void setImagen(String nombreImagen) {
        if (nombreImagen != null) {
            imagen = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(nombreImagen)).getImage();
        } else {
            imagen = null;
        }    
        repaint();
    }

    public void setImagen(Image nuevaImagen) {
        imagen = nuevaImagen;    
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        if (imagen != null) {
            g.drawImage(imagen, 0, 0,null, this);    
            setOpaque(false);
        } else {
            setOpaque(true);
        }    
        super.paint(g);
    }
}
```

But adding the image can not get to stay with rounded corners and shadow repaint.

And also tried to add a JLabel with the image to the panel but not achieving the desired result.

I would appreciate any help.
thanks

Comment: no idea why is downvoted, too hard job

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adjusting [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13368321/1133011) in the link you provided I was able to achieve this (with the help of [How to make a rounded corner image in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7603400/how-to-make-a-rounded-corner-image-in-java) +1 to the author):

[image]

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ShadowTest {

    private JFrame frame;

    public ShadowTest() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ShadowTest();
            }
        });
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);//app exited when frame closes
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gc.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
        frame.add(new RoundedPanel(), gc);

        //pack frame (size components to preferred size)
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);//make frame visible
    }
}

class RoundedPanel extends JPanel {

    /**
     * Stroke size. it is recommended to set it to 1 for better view
     */
    protected int strokeSize = 1;
    /**
     * Color of shadow
     */
    protected Color shadowColor = Color.black;
    /**
     * Sets if it drops shadow
     */
    protected boolean shady = true;
    /**
     * Sets if it has an High Quality view
     */
    protected boolean highQuality = true;
    /**
     * Double values for Horizontal and Vertical radius of corner arcs
     */
    //protected Dimension arcs = new Dimension(0, 0);
    protected Dimension arcs = new Dimension(20, 20);//creates curved borders and panel
    /**
     * Distance between shadow border and opaque panel border
     */
    protected int shadowGap = 10;
    /**
     * The offset of shadow.
     */
    protected int shadowOffset = 4;
    /**
     * The transparency value of shadow. ( 0 - 255)
     */
    protected int shadowAlpha = 150;
    int width = 300, height = 300;
    BufferedImage image;
    BufferedImage roundedImage;

    public RoundedPanel() {
        super();
        setOpaque(false);
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new URL("http://www.wallpaperpimper.com/wallpaper/Anime_&_Manga/Naruto/Naruto-Vs-Sasuke-1-D6UGW3NLAZ-800x600.jpg"));

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        roundedImage = makeRoundedCorner(image, 20);//make image round

        width = roundedImage.getWidth()+arcs.width/2;//set width and height of panel accordingly
        height = roundedImage.getHeight()+arcs.height/2;
    }

    public static BufferedImage makeRoundedCorner(BufferedImage image, int cornerRadius) {
        int w = image.getWidth();
        int h = image.getHeight();
        BufferedImage output = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        Graphics2D g2 = output.createGraphics();

        // This is what we want, but it only does hard-clipping, i.e. aliasing
        // g2.setClip(new RoundRectangle2D ...)

        // so instead fake soft-clipping by first drawing the desired clip shape
        // in fully opaque white with antialiasing enabled...
        g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2.fill(new RoundRectangle2D.Float(0, 0, w, h, cornerRadius, cornerRadius));

        // ... then compositing the image on top,
        // using the white shape from above as alpha source
        g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcAtop);
        g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);

        g2.dispose();

        return output;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Color shadowColorA = new Color(shadowColor.getRed(),
                shadowColor.getGreen(), shadowColor.getBlue(), shadowAlpha);
        Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) g;

        //Sets antialiasing if HQ.
        if (highQuality) {
            graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        }

        //Draws shadow borders if any.
        if (shady) {
            graphics.setColor(shadowColorA);
            graphics.fillRoundRect(
                    shadowOffset,// X position
                    shadowOffset,// Y position
                    width - strokeSize - shadowOffset, // width
                    height - strokeSize - shadowOffset, // height
                    arcs.width, arcs.height);// arc Dimension
        } else {
            shadowGap = 1;
        }

        //Draws the rounded opaque panel with borders.
        graphics.setColor(getBackground());
        graphics.fillRoundRect(0, 0, width - shadowGap,
                height - shadowGap, arcs.width, arcs.height);
        graphics.setColor(getForeground());
        graphics.setStroke(new BasicStroke(strokeSize));
        graphics.drawRoundRect(0, 0, width - shadowGap,
                height - shadowGap, arcs.width, arcs.height);

        graphics.drawImage(roundedImage, 0, 0, this);//draw the rounded image

        //Sets strokes to default, is better.
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(width, height);
    }
}
```

Comment: @user60108 glad to be of help

Answer (score 1):

The actual answer will depend on what your definition of shadow is...

Checkout

- [Java: create shadow effect on image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14655643/java-create-shadow-effect-on-image/14656403#14656403)
- [JPanel Drop Shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13368103/jpanel-drop-shadow/13369038#13369038)

For examples. They both use a similar techniques of masking to generate shadows for non-rectangular shapes which should help

Comment: The OP has linked your second bullet saying *I'm trying to add an image to [this RoundedPane](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13368103/jpanel-drop-shadow/13369038#13369038) with rounded corners and shadow. But I fail to get it.* So I guess he saw your answer now wants an image added to it with round borders too. +1 on first bullet nice shadow effect

Comment: @DavidKroukamp wow, missed that. Can't say it would be hard, might require some clipping, it the basic idea is sound +1 to your answer by the way