# JLabel click effect on it like "Mac OS" System Preference's icons

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, imageicon

I have a `JLabel` on a `JFrame` (Java, Swing) with an `image` on it, but i would like to do something like icons on the system preferences on `Mac OS`, which is a `JLabel` with an image and when you click on it, the image got some kind of shadow all over the image.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please provide example pictures of what you mean and also what you have tried/have so far to help people help you. Thanks. Yu might want to check out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233526/image-with-shadow-and-rounded-edges-in-java-swing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is set the normal icon, as well as a 'shaded' version for the pressed/ rollover icon etc.