# In-built method/flag for applying gaussian blur to objects drawn by Graphics2D?

Tags: java, graphics2d, gaussianblur

Are there any in-built methods, or flags I can set, with a Java Graphics2D object such that I can draw polygons or other shapes with gaussian blur automatically applied?

Or if anyone knows of a computationally efficient shortcut/hack, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK - no. Most blur operations operate on a BufferedImage as they need to manipulate the underlying pixel data. A typical approach is to renderer the content to an image, blur it, then paint that to what ever you want

Comment: I prefer [jhlabs](http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/blurring.html), not the fastest, but among the simplest and gives good quality

Comment: [This is involved answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34123731/add-glow-to-a-basic-java-rectangle/34124063#34124063) but has a fast blur

Comment: [And other example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23215415/create-an-transparent-rectangle-over-blurred-background-in-jframe/23232618#23232618)

Comment: [And if you want to make your eyes bleed](https://github.com/RustyKnight/BlurPane)

Comment: Wow, thanks man. You've given me more than enough for an accepted answer there. If you want to stick any of those comments in an answer, I'll accept it. Tar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK - no.

Most blur operations operate on a `BufferedImage` as they need to manipulate the underlying pixel data. A typical approach is to render the content to an image, blur it, then paint that to whatever you want

I prefer to use [JHLabs](http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/blurring.html) filters generally, they're not the fastest, but generally give a high quality result.

[This example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34123731/add-glow-to-a-basic-java-rectangle/34124063#34124063) is a little involved, but demonstrates the basic idea.

[As another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23215415/create-an-transparent-rectangle-over-blurred-background-in-jframe/23232618#23232618) and if your [really want to make your eyes bleed](https://github.com/RustyKnight/BlurPane) ;)

Comment: Thank you sir :-)